# How to combine the multiple lines in one plot using Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: sql, plot, apache-zeppelin

I have three tables with time series data of the same columns, like:

```
 Time     Values
00:00         48
00:00         34 
00:01         87
00:02         79
00:02          3    
  ...        ...
```

The three tables are of date 0512, 0513 and 0514. Now I want to plot line graphs for each day and put **all there lines** side by side in a single plot for easy comparison. I am currently working on Zeppelin notebook and know how to plot line graph for one particular day:

```
%sql select time, value from df_12 group by time order by time
```

But I dont know how to combine the line graphs for three days into one single plot.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, i think you can build a new dataframe which includes value1, value2, value3 for each line if lines have the same time unit. Then, you can write query to display all values like `%sql select time, value1, value2, value3 from merged_table`. Now, you can draw multiple lines in a single graph.

Comment: Is there any way without the creation of merged table?

Comment: In Zeppelin, each graph (not the line, a graph can include multiple lines) is for a single query result. Thus, if you register all tables and query using multiple `select` and `union`, then you will get a single graph with all necessary columns. But i am not sure whether it would be efficient or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer, which is to use inner join function instead of union, such as:

```
%sql select t1.time, t1.value,coalesce(t2.value,0) as t2_value, 
coalesce(t3.value,0) as t3_value
from
(select time, sum(Values) as value from df_12 group by time) t1
inner join
(select time, sum(Values) as value from df_13 group by time) t2
on t1.time=t2.time
inner join
(select time, sum(Value) as value from df_14 group by time) t3
on t1.time=t3.time
order by time
```